# What is really going on with the `favorites` tab?

Tags: discussion, search, bookmarks

I'm using SO for 2+ years, and I still don't understand the rationale behind the `favorites` tab. I find it useful to track another's question, until I get a good answer. Also, it may be useful for storing questions for a "will answer later" by my-self. Or to store the questions, that I may ask very often, but forget the answer just after I see it. There is a lot of other use-cases.

But even if I have to use this tab for more than a sole purpose - I can't distinguish questions by the reason, I've added them for. Now I have 73 favorite questions - and it's a total mess right now.

### Wait for a good answer?

I've shoveled the meta and found some un-closed feature-requests here and there - about specification of recent changes inside favorite question - and none of these feature-requests have information about on-going work. Which one is in progress? Where can I read the actual info?

Right now, there is no way to find out, what actually has changed about the highlighted question.

### Store to find'n'look an answer quickly?

AFAIK, favorite questions don't affect the top suggested results during the search of the question. So, I have to:

- search the page it-self using a built-in browser search, or
- search the whole SO as "for the first time", or
- look through all of the favorite questions - one by one.

<s>Thus, not useful at all.</s> **Update #1**: may be useful in combo with advanced search and `infavorites:mine`.

### Collect interesting questions?

Not a point - just upvote them, and open the `up-voted questions` tab later.

---

What is the expected usage of the `favorites` tab? What was it planned for?

And the most important question: where can I read the actual official information about planned changes to the `favorites` tab?

Comment: I still think its primary use is to make a question look better by making the number under the star bigger.

Comment: Yeah, I wish at some point of a not distant future, we'd be able to have some kind of tagging system into our favorites.

Comment: `Store to find'n'look an answer quickly?` that's what I use it for.

Answer (score 1):

Giving an upvote to a question doesn't mean it is interesting.  Upvote is a like that the question is a valid question that is useful to our community.

There is difference between useful and interesting.

You can check the reason for upvote [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

> **When should I vote up?**
>
> Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote >it up!
>
> You have a limited number of votes per day, so use them wisely.

Consider each day 30 votes, so it is bit difficult to search your interesting question with your upvotes.

Your view on favorite is right, mark a question as favorite so you can come back easily for view/write an answer.  If you still find it as interesting them keep it starred else you can remove the star from the question.

As per myself, I consider **`favorites`** as *a place where I can mark certain interesting and reference Q and A 's and refer it whenever I get time.*

I think the official place for planned favorite changes would be [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/favorites).

<sup><sub>*The view might differ from each person*</sub></sup>